# How to send a logout message to remote user?

Tags: java, spring, extjs

I have a project builded on java2se, spring, gradle and extjs. I have to implement ability for admin to log out remoted users. I have done this by using method SessionInformation.expireNow(). But additionally users have to see message "Session was aborted by admin" and I don't know how to do it. I tried to use Ext.Msg.alert(), but it works only when admin log out his own session. Message do not appears on remoted user's screen.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you cannot send any messages to user. Instead set a flag - `abortedByAdmin` in the user's session info.

On each user's call check whether the flag is set. If yes respond with the message "Session was aborted by admin" and then clear the session.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I guess, it's unreal. The project is too big. I can't introduce this check in every user request. There are few roles and they have many cotrollers

Comment: You can add the check to a Filter. Just process each request checking the flag for for session from the request.

Answer (score 0):

use any date time variable in database and set it to server current date time at every 5 seconds and check that variable (database field) on every 5 seconds if current date time value and that database field value`s difference is >5 seconds than user did logged out otherwise he is logged in.